# Adding input field value

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add the values from an input field with the values of a variable inside a jquery. When doing so I get `[object Object]` displaying as the result.  My goal is to get the value from the input field so I can then added to a variable and ultimately display on result on another textbox with id called `person`. The texbox I am trying to get the value from is `count`. How can I achieve this?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'person.php',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    var num = $('#count').val(data);
    $('#person').val(num+ newUniqueAI);
    }
});
```

Comment: What is `data`? Why are you passing it to `.val` if you want to retrieve the value? Please read the jQuery documentation: http://api.jquery.com/val/. It contains information about how `.val` should be called.

Comment: You are setting the value of data to count, not getting

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry, I added the whole example.

Comment: So, do you want to *set* the value of `#count` and also use the new value for `#person`? What is the value of `data`? What is `newUniqueAI` and its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#count').val(data);// first set the value     

var num = $('#count').val(); //get by val()
$('#person').val(parseInt(num)+ parseInt(newUniqueAI)); // set by val(something)
```

reference **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)**

Comment: +1 Great but now `(num+ newUniqueAI)` will not add for example if `num=5` and `newUniqueAI =3` I get result `53`. How come?

Comment: @Code_Ed_Student: One of the values (or both) is a string. Convert strings to numbers first, e.g. with the unary `+` operator: `+num`.

Comment: If you use `parseInt`, don't forget to pass the radix as second argument.

Answer (score 3):

You are using:

```
$('#count').val(data);
```

This sets the value of #count to the value of data and returns a jQuery object. You want to get the value of #count. Therefore you should use:

```
$('#count').val();
```

If you do not specify a parameter the val function returns the value. More information about val() could be read here: http://api.jquery.com/val/